# Broadcast not receiving between two custom application

Tags: android, android-broadcastreceiver

My program is about calculating calories of some food. This is a practice for CS course. I'm beginner on Android OS and I do not know why my receiving process cannot be completed or shown on Activity.

I just write the relevant code pieces here. I had some items on sqlite database and I can check my items on database with Log.d method and they are okay.

App1:

Manifest:

```
<receiver android:name="ItemBroadcastReceiver"
            android:exported="true">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.example.furkan.datagenerator" />

    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Received.class

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.received);

    ItemBroadcastReceiver br = new ItemBroadcastReceiver();
    Cursor cursor = (Cursor) br.receivedItem;
    ReceivedItemsAdapter adapter = new ReceivedItemsAdapter(this, cursor);
    ListView listView = getListView();
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

Adapter:

```
public class ReceivedItemsAdapter extends CursorAdapter {
public ReceivedItemsAdapter(Context context, Cursor c) {
    super(context, c);
}

@Override
public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
    View retView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.received, parent, false);

    return retView;
}

@Override
public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
    //ImageView icon = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.icon);
    TextView name = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.name);
    TextView cal = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.amountCal);
    TextView unit = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.unit);
    unit.setText(" cal");
    name.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(cursor.getColumnName(1))));
    cal.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(cursor.getColumnName(2))));

}}
```

Broadcast Receiver:

```
public class ItemBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
Item receivedItem;
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();

    receivedItem = new Item(bundle.getString("name"),
                                Integer.parseInt(bundle.getString("calories")),
                                bundle.getString("category"),
                                null);
}}
```

App2:

MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
final int DELAY = 60000;
ReceivedItem item;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ReceivedItemsDatabaseHelper dbHelper = new        ReceivedItemsDatabaseHelper(this);


    item = new ReceivedItem(dbHelper.fetchReceivedItem().getString(
            dbHelper.fetchReceivedItem().getColumnIndex(
                    dbHelper.fetchReceivedItem().getColumnName(1))),
            Integer.parseInt(dbHelper.fetchReceivedItem().getString(
                    dbHelper.fetchReceivedItem().getColumnIndex(
                            dbHelper.fetchReceivedItem().getColumnName(2)))),
            dbHelper.fetchReceivedItem().getString(
                    dbHelper.fetchReceivedItem().getColumnIndex(
                            dbHelper.fetchReceivedItem().getColumnName(3))), null);

    Thread thread = new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            synchronized (this) {
                try {
                    Log.d("Response ", item.getName()+", "+item.getCategory()+", "+item.getCalories());
                    Intent intent = new Intent();
                    intent.setAction("com.example.furkan.datagenerator");
                    intent.putExtra("name", item.getName());
                    intent.putExtra("calories", item.getCalories());
                    intent.putExtra("category", item.getCategory());
                    sendBroadcast(intent);
                    sleep(DELAY);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        }
    };
    thread.start();
}}
```

Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
filter.addAction("com.example.furkan.datagenerator");

ItemBroadcastReceiver br = new ItemBroadcastReceiver();
registerReceiver(br, filter);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should read about `BroadcastReceivers` again.

```
ItemBroadcastReceiver br = new ItemBroadcastReceiver();
Cursor cursor = (Cursor) br.receivedItem;
ReceivedItemsAdapter adapter = new ReceivedItemsAdapter(this, cursor);
ListView listView = getListView();
listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

This creates a new instance of the receiver and assigns the `receivedItem` to `cursor`. But `receivedItem` is `null` and since you never register `br` for broadcasts, it'll never be not `null`. Also I'm not sure, if `Item` could be cast to `Cursor`.

Considering the code you posted here and the title you used, using `BroadcastReceiver` might not be a good idea at all. You should try to pass data to `Received` via intent or load the data directly from persisted storage.

And at last your `thread` doesn't make any sense.

Comment: I just want to broadcast a random item to other app in each 60 seconds

Comment: Then the problem with casting it to `Cursor` is still valid. You'd have to notify your `Activity` from within the `BroadcastReceiver` about the changes. No global state is stored.